# NGINX - Multiple responses to one request

Tags: nginx

I'm writing a NGINX module, and I would like to know if there is an option to send the client a response in parts? Meaning, in case of large files my server returns the response to the `GET` request in parts, I would like to send each part to the user without saving it to a temp file. I would like each part of the response to be sent and the client will get a few responses to the same request.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)?

Comment: http protocol currently only allows for a single http response to a request. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry for mt English... I would try to explain my self in a better way: I would like my module to send the response it get from the server without saving it in the local memory (file/chain), my problem is that because of the large size , the server send the response in a few chunks, I would like each chunk to be send to the client. I hope I was clear...

Comment: please have a look at this 
http://dret.typepad.com/dretblog/2007/11/one-request-mul.html 

, I think they're trying to say it's not already implemented ,and if it is , then it's not widely used :\